# Place four buttons in the center using auto layout Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

What kind of constraints should I put so that these four buttons are always in the center without effecting their shapes or sizes. Right now I can't seem to find a way to place them in the center as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: You button has fixed width and height ??

Comment: Yes, they have fixed sizes, 67x67.

Comment: @laser2302 give equal height and width constraint and appropriate leading trailing constraint.

Comment: Set 4 buttons in UIView and make this view center horizontally and vertically. Inside this view set 4 buttons relative to new centered view with zero frame.

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to create a `UIView` that is always centered to its superview and has constant dimensions. Inside that view you can put the four buttons with constant sizes and appropriate constraints.

In that way all the button will always be centered.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this diagram helps. Don't forget to give width and height constraints to your button as well.

(sorry for bad handwriting)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIStackView for this. Place the buttons inside stackView, set constraints in reference to the stackView. Then set constraints on stackView to place it in the middle.

Comment: UIStackView is not supported in older versions of iOS, so I want to avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can group all this 4 view in UIStackView element, And defined the **Spacing** property between them, set **Distribution** property to **Fill Equally**. After that set constraint of Stack view according to you view.

Hope you find you solution.

Comment: UIStackView is not supported in older versions of iOS, so I want to avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply--

1.Take a UIView and give it constraints for horizontally and vertically centered and fixed height and width also.

2. Add 4 UIButtons in it with fixed width and height as shown in question.
3. Now add top leading trailing and bottom constraints to all UIButtons.

now your all buttons would be fit as you want......